# Disallow sell of a simple product but allow that product to be sell in bundled product

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, bundled-product, simple-product

I have simple product with SKU say: **SKU01** and **SKU02**

And I have a bundled product with its own SKU say: **SKUB01**,

This **SKUB01** have bundled items consist of two simple SKU: **SKU01** and **SKU02**,

The question is:
I want to disable the selling of **SKU01** meanwhile still be able to sell the bundled product **SKUB01**,

How to do that in Magento v1.9.8?

Answer (score 5):

Just simple solution for that Just Set that simple Product `visibility` to `Not Visible Individually`

Hope this will help you and let me know if its not working

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, I already tried it, the thing is I already have customers that buys that SKU01 in the past... the thing is even if I set it to "Not Visible Individually" now.. that customer still can order it again by using the "Reorder" feature in their "Purchase History" page.. how to deal with this case?

Comment: You can create an array for that kind of product and make check in this event `catalog_product_is_salable_before` and make sure that this product not add to cart

Comment: Are you still looking for answer??

Comment: Won't work, if it's not salable, it cannot be added as part of a bundle either.

Comment: He can make check if simple product has parent then product is salable otherwise that particular simple product is not salable

Comment: let me try first

Comment: OK Try and let me know